# Understanding Createview in SQLITE3

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to understand CREATE VIEW command in SQLite, but getting strange view.

I have a CSV file,

table.csv  / tab separated

```
ID   NAME   AGE ADDRESS     SALARY
1    Paul   32  California  20000.0
2    Allen  25  Texas       15000.0
3    Teddy  23  Norway      20000.0
4    Mark   25  Rich-Mond   65000.0
5    David  27  Texas       85000.0
6    Kim    22  South-Hall  45000.0
7    James  24  Houston     10000.0
```

- run commands*

  ```
   sqlite3 sample.db

    .mode csv

    .import table.csv  COMPANY

    CREATE VIEW COMPANY_VIEW AS
    SELECT "ID", "NAME", "AGE"
    FROM  COMPANY;

    SELECT * FROM COMPANY_VIEW;
  ```

getting

```
"1 ",NAME,"32 "
"2 ",NAME,"25 "
"3 ",NAME,"23 "
"4 ",NAME,"25 "
"5 ",NAME,"27 "
"6 ",NAME,"22 "
"7 ",NAME,"24 "
```

Why I am not getting NAME Column. What I am doing wrong. I am an absolute beginner in SQLITE3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest issuing `.schema COMPANY` and/or `SELECT * FROM COMPANY` before the `CREATE VIEW` command.

From the [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files)

> Use the ".import" command to import CSV (comma separated value) data into an SQLite table.

The operative term here is **comma separated**.

Use the `.separator` command to change the separator to tab.